# What can be done in this video to solve "the air-conditioning problem"?

Tags: audio, video-recording

This [lecture](https://youtu.be/tTxSHmBOEvk?si=u_xkhA_EPoJGql3_&t=703) seems to have been filmed in a classroom with ar conditioning.  I can see the professor is using a microphone that's very close to his mouth.  I would like to also record lectures like that, but I think the sound result is very poor and I'd like to do anything I can do to resolve this.  What could be done?  Would buying a much better microphone really produce a much better result?  Can you recommend all the necessary equipment so that I try it out?  I'm willing to invest a good deal of money in the equipment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The audio on this video isn't from the mic around his neck.
It's from a mic much further away. I would guess the wrong input was selected when the video was filmed. The main noise on the audio is electrical interference because it's a cheap mic in a laptop or phone.

Any radio mic or clip mic around the neck should work better than what we hear in this clip. [Sennheiser](https://www.sennheiser.com/en-gb/catalog/products/wireless-systems/ew-112p-g4/ew-112p-g4-a-509507) make good expensive reliable radio mics. [Rode](https://rode.com/en/microphones/wireless) make some cheaper clever rechargeable models. Even a £10 clip mic plugged into an iPhone in airplane mode and recording into the Voice Memo app can give good results in a situation like this, if you're prepared to re-sync the audio and video afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much for your experience on this.  I did not notice what you did.